# Proving an existence

Tags: arithmetic

I am completely lost on where to go with this one. Can someone provide help with how to do this? I am trying to understand uniqueness.

Here it is:

```
Prove that for every real number x, if x DOES NOT equal 0 and x DOES NOT equal 1 
then there exists a unique real number such that y/x = y - x
```

Comment: Solve for $y$. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: There is no information about y?

Answer (score 3):

cross multiplying
$$
y = x y - x^2 \Rightarrow y = \frac{x^2}{x-1}$$
You now see why $x=0$ and $x=1$ are ruled out.

You can finish the rest

Comment: It's important that your $\Rightarrow$s are really $\Leftrightarrow$s, including the first step where you multiplied through by $x$. ($\Rightarrow$ gives uniqueness, $\Leftarrow$ gives existence.)

Comment: I'm confused though. If we plugged in 0 wouldn't that evaluate to 0^2 / -1) which would then go to 0? thus being a real number

Comment: In the original equation, $\frac{y}{x}$ would be undefined if $x=0$.

Comment: Well you can cross multiply only if $x \ne 0$. Or else you end up with $\frac 0 0$. Who knows what that is!

Comment: @CliveNewstead I agree... I wanted to give a *broad* hint without actually giving the full solution. To go both ways you have to make sure you do not cross multiply by zero and that is why I left the final comment.